# Use environment files outside the directory to provide parameter during build time with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I want to create some different kind of Images that are supplied with some config parameters during the build time. Therefore i found on the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file) that I can use an env_file: in the docker compose like:

```
env_file:
   - /opt/secrets.env
```

But this seems to be not available during build time of the image because when I print the ARGs they are empty. Only if i create an `.env` file in the folder where the `docker-compose.yml` is located it works.

So my question is: Is there a chance to provide parameters like ARG or ENV inside the Dockerfile from an file located outside of the folder tree?

```
tree
|---docker-env/
|    |---docker.env
|
|---docker/
     |---docker-compose.yml
     |---image/
           |---Dockerfile
```

It doesn't matter if this file is loaded inside the Dockerfile or in the docker-compose file and handed to the Dockerfile during build.

Any suggestions or ideas how to set the Parameters or is my approach wrong? How can parameters be used during build time? I'm bit stuck with this currently.

My current minimal setup is the following:

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  default:
    container_name: base
    image: my/base
    build:
      context: image
      args:
        ROOT_PASSWD: $ROOT_PASSWD
    env_file:
      ./../docker-env/docker.env
```

#### Dockerfile

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# stick to Ubuntu 16.04
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.10.2

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# script global definitions

ARG ROOT_PASSWD

RUN echo try $ROOT_PASSWD
```

#### docker.env

```
# docker.env

ROOT_PASSWD=123
```

When I try to build this image with `docker-compose build --no-cache` I get the following output:

```sh
$ docker-compose build --no-cache
WARNING: The ROOT_PASSWD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Building default
Step 1/3 : FROM phusion/baseimage:0.10.2
 ---> 4ca439e72536
Step 2/3 : ARG ROOT_PASSWD
 ---> Running in e3af937c74c2
Removing intermediate container e3af937c74c2
 ---> b4937c9876ec
Step 3/3 : RUN echo try $ROOT_PASSWD
 ---> Running in 1548a0a77100
try
Removing intermediate container 1548a0a77100
 ---> 1802ed0eb009
Successfully built 1802ed0eb009
Successfully tagged my/base:latest
```

On Step 3/3 there is the "try      " but no output from the ARG.

I hope someone can suggest a hint how to solve this.

Comment: If you use jenkins you can write ```ENV ROOT_WASSWD="insert pw"``` and overwrite the "insert pw" string on building. For secrets like passwords you can even inject them from a jenkins secret, so you don't have them anywhere visible inside your repo.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but jenkins can't be used for this step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `arg` option does not support reading from the file. and `ENV` will not work in `build` stage.

the best you can do is to use only `args` in your `dockerfile` and pass them with build command:

```
export test=1;export ROOT_PASSWD=123;docker-compose build
```

if you have too many variable in the file try this:

```
for i in $(cat < .env); do export $i;done && docker-compose build
```

or you can specify them in `compose` manually:

```
args:
        ROOT_PASSWD: 123
```

Comment: And there are no other ways to provide these ARGS to the docker-compose file except to export these before?

Comment: Year thanks, this get me the idea how to deal with it. I create a small script that copy the file to the directory and name it .env. Then execute docker-compose and remove the .env file. This worked fine for me.